# Quantum Optimization as approximating $\mathbb{CP}^{2^n -1}$ with the orbits of a subgroup of SU($2^n$)

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, lie-groups, quantum-mechanics, approximation-algorithms, applied-mathematics

For example given a great circle within the sphere, we can think about computing the average distance of a point on the sphere from the great circle. Slightly more generally, given a subgroup $H \subset $ SU(n) and a point $p \in \mathbb{CP}^{n-1}$ one can think about the subspace $Hp$ consisting of the images $hp$ where $h \in H$. Then we can ask how closely $Hp$ approximates $\mathbb{CP}^{n-1}$ under the Fubini-Study metric. I am interested both in the farthest a point in $q \in \mathbb{CP}^{n-1}$ could be from $Hp$ and in the average distance from a point in $\mathbb{CP}^{n-1}$ to $Hp$.

This problem is highly relevant for understanding the capacity of near-term quantum computers. In this context, we can understand the subgroup $H$ as the restricted set of gate operations we are permitted to apply and $p \in \mathbb{CP}^{n-1}$ as the initial quantum state to which we apply gates, so that the approximation question corresponds to how accurately we can reach any state given limited resources.

In particular, this corresponds to finding a worse-case bound on the [Quantum Approximate Optimization Algorithm](https://arxiv.org/abs/1411.4028).

**Addendum**

In particular I am interested in subgroups of SU($2^n$). The pauli matrices $ i\sigma_1, i \sigma_2, i \sigma_3$ form a basis for $ \mathfrak{su}(2)$ (note that this matches the fact that dim(SU(n)) = $n^2 - 1$). Similarly the n-fold tensor products of pauli matrices and the identity (e.g  $i\sigma_1 \otimes \sigma_3 \otimes \sigma_2 \otimes I \otimes \cdots $) form a basis for $\mathfrak{su}(2^n)$. I can restrict to a subset $B$ of this basis, then add the other necessary basis elements to m ake a set closed under the bracket $C$. Then the Lie Algebra generated by the basis $C$ is $\mathfrak{g} \subset \mathfrak{su}(2^n)$. Now the Lie subgroup of SU($2^n)$ I care about is $G = e^{\mathfrak{g}}$.

In the interest of being concrete as possible I will pick a low-dimensional example. Lets focus on SU($2^2$)  acting on $\mathbb{CP}^{2^2 -1}$ - this corresponds to a system with 
2 qubits. I decide to examine the Lie Algebra generated by the set $\{IX + XI, ZZ\}$. This generates a five-dimensional subgroup QAOA($2^2$) of $SU(2^2)$. Since $dim(\mathbb{CP}^{3}) = 6$, I know that the subspace QAOA($2^2$) p is a proper subset of $\mathbb{CP}^{3}$. I then want to know how well QAOA($2^2$) p approximates $\mathbb{CP}^{3}$.

This method of limiting your basis set corresponds to restricting the allowed quantum gates which you will apply on your device. In particular I want to restrict my gate set as much as possible while maximizing my ability to approximate arbitrary states.

*In the long-term this line of inquiry aims to provide [approximation ratios](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximation_algorithm) for quantum optimization algorithms*

Comment: To be clear, is the problem you want to solve about finding the the maximum distance of a point of $\mathbb{CP}^{n-1}$ from an orbit of $H$, for all subgroups $H \subset SU(n)$? There is no list of all subgroups of $SU(n)$, so could you perhaps give a more specific choice of which subgroups $H$ you are most interested in.

Comment: In general I would like to know what are reasonable techniques to think about in this context.